# Piping two child processes, one for ls, the other for sort, but sort is not working

Tags: c, sorting, unix, piping

I'm trying to create two child processes and pipe them, but the second child is not sorting the output produced by the first child which does ls. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pipefd[2];
  pid_t ls_pid, wc_pid;

  pipe(pipefd);

  if ((ls_pid = fork()) == 0) {

    dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);

    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", 0);
    perror("exec ls failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  if ((wc_pid = fork()) == 0) {

    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

    close(pipefd[1]);
    execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", NULL);
    perror("exec wc failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "but the second child is not sorting the output". What is the exact behaviour?

Comment: second child just puts every item of ls in a new line

Comment: Ok, but is the output sorted? I tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: In both child processes, you should close both ends of the pipe after you've used `dup2()` to connect one end to standard input or output.  If the parent was going to wait for the children, it would be crucial for it to close both ends of the pipe too.  Note that the output from `ls` is sorted anyway; `ls | sort` may not do anything useful (but `sort -r` would show an effect).  Because the parent does nothing after creating the children, your prompt is probably lost in the output.  Simply hitting return enters an empty command, or you could type `echo Finished` and you'd see `Finished` echoed.

Answer (score 1):

The sort should work, but there are 2 caveats in your code, first, make sure close fd in all the processes that holds references to the fd, otherwise the fd won't close, and that's why the sort process hangs there when done, because it does not receive the EOF from stdin, and that's because the pipefd in the parent process were not closed. The other one is make sure wait the children to exit and check their exit status. Add the following to the send of main function:

```
close(pipefd[0]);
close(pipefd[1]);

int status;
int pid = waitpid(ls_pid, &status, 0);
pid =  waitpid(wc_pid, &status, 0);
```

Comment: Because the parent exits, effectively running the kids in the background, it doesn't really matter that the parent doesn't explicitly close the pipes; they're closed by the system when it exits.  However, if the parent was to hang around and wait for the children to complete, then it would indeed be crucial that it close both ends of the pipe.

Comment: Yes, as this is a process that output stuff on standard output, not one that runs in background like a daemon, I think it's kind of weird when the parent exits and you still see stuff output on the console, that's why I'd suggest wait for children to exit before the parent finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `NULL` as the third parameter of the firt`execl` just like you do in the second one. What happens is that `execl` executes correctly (that's why you dont get an error) but the `ls` command does not work as you give it an invalid command.
Btw, you should make error control on all OS requests, like in `fork()`

Comment: But the ls is working, the sort is what is not technically working. The sort only makes every item of ls print to a new line in stdout. I tried it and it is still the same

Comment: I think your sort is doing nothing at all, try adding `system("pstree")` before the end of the parent process and see if there is a sort process unfinished. You also run your code and then run `pstree` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Combining all comments, and tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pipefd[2];
  pid_t ls_pid, wc_pid;
  int status;

  pipe(pipefd);

  if ((ls_pid = fork()) == 0) {

    dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    perror("exec ls failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }


  if ((wc_pid = fork()) == 0) {

    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
    perror("exec sort failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  close (pipefd[0]);
  close (pipefd[1]);

  /* wait for two children to finish */
  wait(&status);
  wait(&status);


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```